# Flutter cannot load image from url

Tags: java, android, dart, flutter

I have an huge error when I try loading images from an url in flutter. I have uploaded it to hastebin: https://hastebin.com/iguvopihog.m

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test/news.dart';

void main() => runApp(new Main());

class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Image.network('www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'),
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Test"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: null),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered writing "http://www"... instead of "www"... ?
You usually never give a like without specifying the protocole, or the computer will think that you want to access the local folder "www.google.de" instead of the actual server.

Answer (score 23):

For some reason `Image.network` seems to interpret the URL as file path.

Try instead setting the protocol explicitely:

```
body: new Image.network('http://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'),
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I am new to flutter that is why I do not know how to do that. I did not find any suitable parameters in #network.

Comment: No worries. SO is here to get questions answered. Your question did provide the necessary information for others to answer it, that is IMHO the most important part.

Comment: for more information please refer url https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html

Comment: @AarifAli thanks for your attempt to improve my answer! The changes were substantial and I'd suggest to post it as your own answer instead.